# how many five letter words can be made using the letters PLANT? a word is seen as any combination of the letters.

Tags: combinatorics

(the word does not need to make sense in any language, just a 5 letter combination, repetition of letters is not allowed)
Hi, am I supposed to use the floor function of $e*n!$ for this question? I had thought about using $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ where $n$ is the number of letters in plant and $k$ is the number of letters we want in the word but this is incorrect. any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Let's build a word from scratch. How many ways can I pick the first letter? After then, how many ways can I pick the second? The third? The fourth? The fifth?

Comment: Isn’t it simply $5!$?

Answer (score 2):

> Hi, am I supposed to use the floor function of e*n! for this question?

Not at all; you are *not* counting *derangements* -combinations in which no letter appears in its original position- (which, by the way, would be counted by $[5!/e]$, the nearest-integer rounding of the ratio, but that is still *not what you need*).

You are simply counting the arrangements, or permutations, of the set.

> I had thought about using n!/(n-k)! where n is the number of letters in plant and k is the number of letters we want in the word but this is incorrect.

No it is not incorrect; you just have to substitute in the value for $n$ and $k$.   $5!/(5-5)!$ *does* count the ways to select and arrange five letters from a set of five letters, *without replacement*.   Sometimes this is written as $^5\mathrm P_5$, or just $5!$ .

Or simply $120$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no repeated leters, this is a pretty simple problem.

Solution:

There are 5 choices for the first position, 4 for the second, 3rd for the third, and so on. Multiplying these all out we have the answer as $5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=5!=120$.

Sidenote:

If there were any repeated letters in the word, you would take the factorial of the total number of letters in the word and divide it by the factorial of the number of times the repeated letter is repeated. For example, the number of ways **BETTER** could be written is $\frac{6!}{2!}=360$, and the number of ways **EEAA** could be written is $\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}=6$.

The proof for this is that if all the letters were different, and there were n letters, there would be $n!$ ways to permute this word. However, if some letters were repeated, and they were repeated m times, they are counted $m!$ times, so we have to divide by $m!$. It is m! for the same reason the total ways for the word is n!.